# How to find required size of AC gear motor for planetary mixing application?

Tags: motors, gears

I want to find a suitable AC or DC gear motor for concrete paste mixing. The application details are given below

Material type - concrete paste
RPM - 30-200rpm
Qty of material - 30Liters
Mixing style - Planetary
To understand the type of mixer, you may consider bakery mixer.

Can somebody help me how to calculate the capacity of gear motor that I have to select for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete mixers usually have 3-4 blades attached to the walls of the mixer and rotating with the mixer tilted 60-70 degrees. Let's assume the diameter of the mixer 0.5 meters

Assuming the blades lifting up carry half of the weight of the mix,
$$w=30/2 (2.5)\space with 2.5 = density\space of\space mix. $$
 w = 37.5 kg. And the work mixer has to do at 100rpm is

$$W = (37.5)9.8.100( 0.5)/60seconds/mins= 306.25 watts$$
This is a very rough approximation. One would need to consider the clumping of the concrete, potentially clutching of the mixer, etc. So for a 200rpm mixer, you'd need a 612-watt motor, say one horsepower.

Comment: Thank you. the concrete mixer I referred here is not tilted one. it is a platform mount mixer. any way tilt angle is not used in your formula. I have to consider a height of the material. in this case, will it be a some other formula considering shear stress and viscosity of the material?

Comment: Why not take what has been offered and adapt it now to match your own assumptions or that which was not clearly stated in your question...